# About me too long but less than 3000 characters

Tags: bug, profile-page

Currently I cannot save my about me, because

> > - About Me is too long

but it seems to be less than 3000 characters - a message which otherwise appears. That is, if the text is more than 3000 characters, the message is:

> > Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
> >     - About Me is limited to 3000 characters; you entered 3046
> >     - About Me is too long

So here it is clear that the text needs to shortened by 46 characters.

What are the criteria for concluding that it is too long?

Edit: It seems to be related to the number of links, too: I removed a link to do reviews quickly, and voila it works. Unfunny.

Comment: Use a binary search pattern to find out.  Continue cutting your content in half, or adding half of the cut content back in, until you've zeroed in on the max allowable size.  It'll take no more than log2(3000) attempts (and that's to get to within 1 character, it'll take less to get within a small margin of error).

Comment: It is more like 2^3000, or even a higher base...

Comment: There appears to be 2 separate messages - one for too long, and one for longer than 3000 characters (I managed to trigger the longer than 3000 characters one without triggering the too long one).

Comment: What do you mean?  You mean, after counting the links, spaces and everything, you still can't get to 3000 characters?  How many usable characters do you have?  I used Microsoft Word on your edit window to check the character count.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Currently, if I add `[tag:c]` I get the error message. But if I add the text _tax_c_xxxxxx it is ok. So there is a "secret", unfunny, limit on the number of links.